# одинаковые проверки в некоторых функциях контроллеров

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, controller

возник вопрос: возможно ли каким либо образом сделать общую логику на некоторые контроллеры и функции внутри контроллера?

> К примеру есть несколько ссылок:
>
> api/user.stats
>
> api/reaction.add
>
> api/reaction.edit
>
> api/reaction.del
>
> и так далее.

и к примеру все они в аргументах принимают поля: `key`, `id`(`api/reaction.add?key=...&id=...`),

вопрос: могу ли я не писать в каждой функции контролера(ControllerBase) проверки на 2 этих аргумента, а где-то один раз написать, чтобы эти функции автоматический в первую очередь проверялись на эти данные?

пример проверки:

```cs
public string stats(string key, int id)
{
    // проверка существует ли папка пользователя
    if (!Directory.Exists($"путь\{id}")
        return "{\"error\": \"Пользователь не создан\"}";

    // проверка ключа
    if (File.ReadAllText($"путь\{id}\key.txt") != key)
        return "{\"error\": \"Не верный ключ\"}";

    ...
}
```

Comment: Что именно вы в этих пргументах проверяете? Покажите код проверки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант сделать атрибут, в котором будет идти проверка Request.QueryString нужных параметров. Далее на нужные методы повышать данный атрибут. При некорректных параметрах возвращать BadRequest. Если это .Net Core, то можно и Middleware сделать.